# Gradle/Java getting "mystery options" out of nowhere

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, windows-10

I have a project in IntelliJ IDEA with some Gradle tasks. Whenever I run one of the tasks, it will initialize then throw me this error:

```
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4G
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
```

The culprit here is that *somewhere* I am setting an option -Xmx4G but I cannot figure out where. My _JAVA_OPTIONS is set to `-Xmx1200M -Xms1200M` however it is completely ignoring this. I am using java jdk1.8_211.

I have tried setting a gradle.properties, changing the system-wide gradle.properties, changing _JAVA_OPTIONS and using a different JDK but I can't get it.

Could someone help me find where this option is set?

Comment: Does it work if you build by Gradle from command line? Have you tried `org.gradle.jvmargs`?

Comment: No, on the command line it gets the exact same error. I have tried org.gradle.jvmargs but it is ignored.